# Azure Functions blob trigger more reliable than WebJobs blob trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-blob-storage

If your read the documentation on Azure WebJobs with blob storage triggers, they mention that this is not very reliable:

*The WebJobs SDK scans log files to watch for new or changed blobs. This process is not real-time; a function might not get triggered until several minutes or longer after the blob is created. In addition, storage logs are created on a "best efforts" basis; there is no guarantee that all events will be captured. Under some conditions, logs might be missed. If the speed and reliability limitations of blob triggers are not acceptable for your application, the recommended method is to create a queue message when you create the blob, and use the QueueTrigger attribute instead of the BlobTrigger attribute on the function that processes the blob.*
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Blobs

I would assume that they use the same functionality for Azure Functions, but there I could not find anything about it. 
Anyone knows more about this? Has this changed or is this still the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Functions use exactly the same way to watch for changed blobs, and same code of `BlobTrigger`. So, the same remark applies to Functions.

Another possibility to react on Blob events is to use [Event Grid trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid).